# Add hex number to a character's code point

Tags: java, unicode

I came across an instruction I needed for my program.

> Append the lowercase version of the current input character (add 0x0020 to the character's code point) to the current tag token's tag name.

Now I can do this with `Character.toLowerCase(someChar);`

But how would you do this manually? That is, how can you append a hex number to a character code point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` primitive is an unsigned integer type in Java, so you can just add a hex literal value to the character:

```
System.out.println((char) ('A' + 0x20)); // "a"
```

Note that you need to cast back to `char` because the arithmetic operation widens the result to `int`.

If you assign the result of the operation back to a variable of type `char`, you don't need the explicit cast:

```
char a = 'A' + 0x20;
System.out.println(a); // "a"
```